# dotnetnuke and dotimage problem

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotimage

I created a module for dotnetnuke that uses Atalasoft's dotImage viewer.   dotImage uses and iframe for "ajax" rendering.  My module works great on the home page but in any other page the module loads the whole home page  in the dotImage iframe.

Has anybody worked with both dotnetnuke and dotImage?

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

I am from Atalasoft. You should open a support case with us so that we can help you.

In any case, the usual reason for a page showing up in a frame is that there was an exception thrown while generating the contents of the frame -- what you are seeing is the custom 500 page for DotNetNuke.

Probably the easiest way to see what's going on is to temporarily turn off custom error pages in your web.config -- then the problem will show up in the frame and you can fix it.  At this point it could be a lot of things (file permissions, not having a license installed correctly, etc) -- so getting the exception is key to solving this.

You turn off custom errors this way:

Look for section like this in your web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
     <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
     <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
</customErrors>
```

Make sure that it is uncommented and then change mode in the customErrors node to "Off"